# Can i perform this step?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> a,b $\in$ R
>
> $${5^{a-b}}\cdot{27^{-(a+b)}}={5^1}\cdot {27^1} \Rightarrow a^{2}-b^{2}=?$$

My Solution:

$a-b=1$

$a+b=-1$  then $a=0$ ; $b=-1$

Since $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, I believe, I cannot perform above solution. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, you cannot do that step since $a$ and $b$ are **real** numbers.

Comment: @idea that’s not true. $5^x=7$ has a solution $x=\log_57$.

Comment: To debug an incorrect argument replace $27$ by $25 = 5^2$ and notice what goes wrong when you apply the same argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $(a,b)=(0,-1)$ we have 
$$5^{a-b}\cdot27^{-(a+b)}=5^1\cdot27^1,$$
and $a^2-b^2=-1$, and that for $(a,b)=\left(\frac{\log(5^1\cdot27^1)}{\log(5/27)},0\right)$ we have
$$5^{a-b}\cdot27^{-(a+b)}=5^a\cdot27^{-a}=\left(\frac{5}{27}\right)^{\frac{\log(5^1\cdot27^1)}{\log(5/27)}}=5^1\cdot27^1,$$
and $a^2-b^2=\left(\frac{\log(5^1\cdot27^1)}{\log(5/27)}\right)^2\geq0$. So the value of $a^2-b^2$ is not uniquely determined by the given equation. In particular, this shows that the step you took is not valid.

Answer (score -2):

In the above equation a and b are not whole numbers but real numbers
$a-b=1$

$a+b=-1$

We know that
$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

$a^2-b^2=(-1)(1)$
$a^2-b^2=-1$

Comment: This is incorrect, see my comment.

Comment: This is correct answer you r right about powers but still

Comment: This answer is incorrect - see the comments on the question.